# Which one sounds better--- 'cannibalism' or 'eating human flesh'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, writing

I was going through a text about ancient civilization. There, I found a sentence which says, "Some ancient human being recognized even cannibalism." After reading that sentence, I started to think that, as the word 'cannibalism' is disgusting, the writer would had written this sentence in another way e.g. "Eating human flesh too was practiced by some human beings in ancient period." What do you think about which one of them sounds better--- 'cannibalism' or 'eating human flesh'?

Comment: Cannibalism is a broadly used term to describe the eating of human flesh. Why do you think it sounds disgusting?

Comment: For the love of... Please consider how this question topic sounds out of context.  Sheesh.

Comment: High-toned people eaters engage in [anthropophagy](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/medical/anthropophagy).

Comment: Are you _sure_ you transcribed that sentence correctly? Also, I agree with Rathony; if anything, I'd be more bothered by "eating human flesh" than by the well-established term for it. The act of cannibalism may be disgusting, but the word itself isn't.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. "Some ancient human being recognized even cannibalism."
> 2. "Eating human flesh too was practiced by some human beings in ancient period."

(1) and (2) don't even mean the same thing.

(1) could mean a particular ancient human being (let's call him Fred) accepted the practice of cannibalism.

(1) could mean Fred could watch another human being eating yet a third human being and say, "Hey, that's cannibalism".

(2) just means they did it (Fred, Barney, whoever).  Recognized or not.

Context would probably shed more light on (1)

Comment: I don't think that *recognize* here means to discern.  I think it means to consider as legitimate.

Comment: @deadrat without context it's hard to tell.  How do you like it now?

Comment: Enough to upvote.

Comment: @deadrat Yabadabado! :)